# How to remove Date from output?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query which gives the output as shown below.

```
SELECT *,
       DATEADD(SECOND, ( DATEDIFF(SECOND, InTime, OutTime) ), 0) AS Total
FROM   TableXYZ
```

---

```
EmpName InTime  OutTime DayStart    NameOfMonth YearSet Total
ABC 12:11:32    21:53:24    Day1    November    2016    1/1/00 9:41
DEF 12:05:56    21:20:58    Day1    November    2016    1/1/00 9:15
```

I tried to remove date from Total but doesn't work. how can I do that and get the output below?

```
EmpName InTime  OutTime DayStart    NameOfMonth YearSet Total
ABC 12:11:32    21:53:24    Day1    November    2016    9:41
DEF 12:05:56    21:20:58    Day1    November    2016    9:15
```

Comment: Is it ever possible that `OutTime - InTime` can exceed 24 hours?

Answer (score 4):

As you are working with SQL Server 2014 you could cast/convert as a time (started in SQL 2008)

```
SELECT *,
cast(DATEADD(SECOND, ( DATEDIFF(SECOND, InTime, OutTime) ), 0) as time(0)) AS Total
FROM   TableXYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of your date calculation is being treated as a date by SQL.  Try converting to a varchar value, then isolate the part you want returned.  There might be cleaner solutions, but this one does the trick:

```
SELECT  right(convert(varchar(19),DATEADD(SECOND, ( DATEDIFF(SECOND, getdate(), getdate()) ), 0),120),8)
```

This query converts the date to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format, then gets the rightmost 8 characters.